# ASP NET CORE Identity - kick user immediately after changing roles

Tags: asp.net-core, session, identity

I've an ASP NET CORE 3.1 mvc app which uses the default identity with cookie based authorization and there is a page where Admin users can give roles to other users.

After successfully changed roles I call `userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user)` to force end the user's session and kick him out.

By default, the roles are stored in the cookie and they're not updated until the user resign-in or the default `SecurityStampValidatorOptions` interval (30 min) passes.

When I give someone roles, I can tell him to resign and this is not a big deal, **but when I remove his roles I would like him to be kicked out immediately.**

The easiest solution is to set the `SecurityStampValidatorOptions.ValidationInterval` to 0 and this fixes the main problem, but of course, this approach leads to big performance issue because the app will execute a query to the database **on every single request** to validate the security stamp.

What is the proper solution of this situation?

Answer (score 0):

By default, when we delete the user's role information, the logged-in account will still retain the permissions, which will be applied only after logging out.

I found a way to update roles on login. When I try to `RefreshSignInAsync(user)`
after removing the role, I see it works.

Inject `SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager` into your controller, and then

```
result = await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, model.RoleName);
if(result.Succeeded)
{
    await signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
}
```

Test Result:

Only `Manager` can access `Test`:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View();
}
```

When tom logs in, he retains the role of `Manager`:

[image]

[image]

Access `Test`:

[image]

Then remove tom from `Manager` and access `Test`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but this will update the user's roles immediately only if I set SecurityStampValidatorOptions.ValidationInterval to 0, which leads to performance problems.